# Redirect subdomain (weblog) to new domain without access to .htaccess

Tags: google-search-console, subdomain, 301-redirect

I have a blog that has PR 1 on a subdomain `aaaa.domain.com` of a blog server `domain.com`.

Now I want to buy a domain `newdomain.com` and I want to tell google webmaster to redirect the old subdomain to this new domain and send traffic to my new domain. I can't access .htaccess to use a 301 redirect. The only thing that I can do is put html code in the html.

How can I do this? When I use "Change of Address" in google webmaster it say:"Restricted to root level domains only".

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Webmaster Tools to inform about switching from subdomain to a totally different domain. More info [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83106).
Regarding the PR 1 - it is not for your subdomain, but for the domain. Your blog hosting platform has PR 1, not your blog.

You should setup 301 redirect from sub.olddomain.com to www.newdomain.com. You should assist your blog hosting provider for this.
It is probably done automatically when you add your own domain using hosting provider control panel.

In addition, you should setup a 301 redirect from newdomain.com to www.newdomain.com.

Comment: It is the individual page that has PR 1 (PageRank), not the domain or "blog hosting platform". +1 The blog hosting provider will _probably_ assist in the 301 redirect if using a domain for the blog is a service they provide.

Comment: You are right about PR in this case. For big platforms, with many subdomains, Google assign PR for each subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

There might be an option in your subdomain's control panel to do redirects. You might also be able to do it in PHP, by e.g. altering the template file and use the header() command (of course other languages have a similar command). Are you sure you only can use HTML code?

Make sure, as eitanpo says, to do a 301 redirect. This will help Google to understand you're moving, and it will update its data based on that. There are ways to redirect in HTML only (JavaScript or HTTP META refresh), but they won't give the visitor (incl. Google) any indication that your (previous) site is abandoned.